# The keyboard shortcuts menu doesn't show any description for Timeline

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, timeline, keyboard-shortcuts

When the "Enable Keyboard Shortcuts" option is enabled, one can press <kbd>?</kbd> to open the shortcuts menu or press other keys to open submenus. Those menus display the available keys and their corresponding description/action.

For example, pressing <kbd>M</kbd> while on a post's page opens the following submenu:

[image: 'moderate' submenu]

Now, while on that menu, pressing <kbd>I</kbd> opens the following submenu:

[image: 'post issues' submenu]

As you can see, the <kbd>T</kbd> key is missing a description.

Pressing it navigates to the post's timeline, so, I would imagine it should be:

[image: 'post issues' submenu (fix)]

An alternative solution would be to get rid of the "post issues" submenu altogether (since it only contains one item) and replace it with "<kbd>T</kbd> timeline". I actually prefer this option because "post issues" isn't very descriptive (that's unless there are plans to add more items to it or if there are already existing ones that I don't have enough privileges to see).

Comment: We're going to look into this as part of our regular bug duty rotation. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed.

"Post issues" refers to the section of controls underneath the voting controls. This includes the timeline on all posts, and can also include flags and deleted comments when these exist, for users who are authorized to see them. So the option to just remove "Post issues" completely from the keyboard shortcut and replace it with the timeline is not one that we will be going with.

That said, the titles for `timeline`, `flags`, and `deleted comments` are now being displayed properly under the "Post issues" section within keyboard shortcuts.

> want some post issues?
> use keyboard shortcuts
> now includes titles